# C++ Winsock2 connect() loop leads to huge memory consumption

Tags: c++, winsock, winsock2

This is my first time coding something using WinSock2 and I tried making a simple chat program which should detect if the server disconnected and then should try to reconnect until a successful connection has been made. (Also: the client connects to server via a No-IP DNS) This is the code:

main.cpp:

```
void keepAliveSEND(const char* IP, int port) {
    TCPClient ack(IP, port);
    ack.connecttcp();
    while (true) {
        ack.synchronizeSEND();
        ack.synchronizeGET();
    }
}

void keepAliveGET(TCPClient* client, const char* IP, int port) {
    TCPClient ack(IP, port);
    ack.connecttcp();

    unsigned long nonblock = 1;
    ioctlsocket(ack.ssocket, FIONBIO, &nonblock);

    while (true) {
        auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        bool loop = true;
        bool timeout = true;
        while (loop) {
            char recvbuff[1024];
            int ByteReceived = 0;
            ByteReceived = recv(ack.ssocket, recvbuff, sizeof(recvbuff), 0);
            if (ByteReceived > 0) {
                std::string str = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < ByteReceived; i++) {
                    str += recvbuff[i];
                }
                timeout = false;
            }
            auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1);
            long ldur = duration.count();
            if (ldur >= 2000) {
                loop = false;
                if (timeout) {
                    client->reconnect();
                    ack.reconnect();
                }
            }
        }
        ack.synchronizeSEND();
    }
}

int main() {
    using namespace std;
    TCPClient client(DNS, 4444);
    client.connecttcp();
    thread t(keepAliveGET, &client, DNS, 4443);
    thread t2(keepAliveSEND, DNS, 4442);
    while (true) {
        //Chat-Code only active upon succesful connection and startchat-command from user
    }

    return 0;
}
```

TCPClient.cpp:

```
void TCPClient::connecttcp() {
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    ADDRINFO hints;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    ADDRINFO *res;
    getaddrinfo(HostIP, NULL, &hints, &res);
    char ipbuf[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    InetNtop(AF_INET, &((SOCKADDR_IN*)res->ai_addr)->sin_addr, ipbuf, sizeof(ipbuf));
    this->IP = ipbuf;

    ssocket = WSASocketW(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    ServerAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ServerAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    InetPton(AF_INET, (PCSTR)IP, &ServerAddr.sin_addr.s_addr);

    while (connect(ssocket, (SOCKADDR*)&ServerAddr, sizeof(ServerAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}

void TCPClient::reconnect() {
    closesocket(ssocket); //EDIT1: Added this line, doesn't change anything
    while (connect(ssocket, (SOCKADDR*)&ServerAddr, sizeof(ServerAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}


void TCPClient::synchronizeSEND() {
    sendData("ACK");
}

void TCPClient::synchronizeGET() {
    while (true) {
        std::string Ack = receiveData(3);
        if (Ack == "ACK") {
            return;
        }
    }
}

void TCPClient::closeConnection() {
    closesocket(ssocket);
    WSACleanup();
}
```

When the server closes and then starts again it will listen on port 4444,4443&4442 for ingoing connections and this is why I want to call `connect()` to reconnect.

When `connecttcp()` is called for the first time (upon execution) only 0.9MB RAM are being used up by this process. But as soon as the server disconnects and thus `reconnect()` is called the RAM starts rising quite a bit reaching almost 1.5GB in about 15 seconds which is not acceptable behaviour. I tried to debug the code in Visual Studio an it seems that `connect(ssocket, (SOCKADDR*)&ServerAddr, sizeof(ServerAddr))` is causing the memory to go up. But it's still able to reconnect...

I already tried to call `closesocket(ssocket)` before reconnecting but that didn't help either...
I read somewhere that Winsock waits up to 4min before it frees the `connect()` resources. Could that be why it behaves like that?

How can I solve this sort of thing?

Comment: What are you doing on connection closed? How, when and where are you calling `reconnect`? Please try to create a [mcve], and [edit] your question to show it to us. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to *debug* your code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I didn't include the detection code because it's kind of long (all in all about 800 rows of code) but in that case I'm going to do include it

Comment: Two problems: First is that you must close the current connection before trying to use the socket for a new connection (call `closesocket`); The second is that you have a possible data-race with the `client` socket in the `keepAliveGET` thread. The leaking you experience is probably because you don't close the connection, which doesn't release resources allocated for it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude As I stated in my post I already tried using closesocket. The problem with this function is that it actually takes several minutes until the resources are released because of potential residual sends from the server. That actually pretty common. But I don't want to Sleep() for several minutes until everything is released because it should reconnect faster. And KeepAliveGET is a seperate TCPClient that uses a different port so I don't really see why any data-racing should happen.

Comment: In the `main` function you have `thread t(keepAliveGET, &client, DNS, 4443);`, passing a pointer to the `client` object. This object is used in the `keepAliveGET` function as `client->reconnect();` without any protection or synchronization. If this `client` object is used from another thread, then you have a data-race.

Comment: ohh thats what you mean. I accidentally left out a piece of code that was in the chat function :/ sorry for my stupdity. The other code that uses client is only active if there's an active connection AND the user specified to start the chat (which is only possible after it connected) so these two things won't interfere with each other. TL;DR The other code using client is only active after succesful connection. But this still doesn't explain why the memory usage is rising that much even tho the client always reconnects succesfully...

Comment: I bypassed this whole problem with a little workaround. It's not beautiful but at least it works. Upon detecting a disconnect a new Process of itself is launched and then it Terminates itself. This way it basically restarts the Client every time the server disconnects and it works but it's not a good solution